# Get distance to closest highway using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I dont think there's a simple way to get the distance to the closest highway using Google maps' API, does someone have an idea how this could be done?

Can you search for highway ramps, and then calculate the distance using DistanceMatrix?